# solving differential recursive equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to solve the equation, I call it a *differential recursive equation*,
$$y_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}f(x)\frac{dy_{n-1}(x)}{dx},\qquad n=1,2,3,...$$
for $y_n(x)$, where
$$y_0(x)=x$$
$y(x)$ and $f(x)$ are differentiable functions of $x$. Is there any general method to solve such recursive and differential equations?
Thanks in advance

**Edit**:

to make it more clear, I assume that $0\le x\le 1$, and $f(x)=a+bx+cx^2+hx^3$.

Comment: This is an interesting sort of problem! I bet there would be interesting solutions for other forms of the recursive equation, but given that we have a continuity constraint and if we restrict our attention to a specific interval of $x$ at any given time, the only sensible solutions seem to be $y_n\to 0$ or $y_n\to\infty$ because of the $\frac{1}{n}$ eventually dominating (or not, if you had a function that did not have uniformly bounded derivatives, and when they are not uniformly bounded they tend to grow exponentially).

Comment: Note that $y_1(x)=f(x)$, $y_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}[f(x)f'(x)]$ and then all succesive terms are of the form $y_k(x)=\frac{1}{k!}g(f,f',...f^{(k-1)})$ for some $g$ (essentially repeated applications of the product rule). To talk about convergence when $n\to\infty$ you'd require at least that $f\in C^\infty$.